# How to scroll down a certain distance on click jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, scroll, jquery-animate

I'm trying to scroll the page down when I click a button with an animation to a certain distance, currently, I'm able to scroll down to a certain element but this is not what I want, I want to scroll down to a certain distance in pixels.

I've tried lots of variation but they don't seem to work in my case, at least not how I want them to.

Anyway, here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.next_section').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.img_div').offset().top
        }, 1000);
   }); 
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> to a certain distance

I assume distance in pixels?

This scrolls down 150px:

```
var y = $(window).scrollTop();  //your current y position on the page
$(window).scrollTop(y+150);
```

@therealbischero (thanks!) mentions in a comment the missing part of my answer, how to make it smoothly scrolling:

```
var y = $(window).scrollTop();
 $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: y + 150 })
```

Comment: This is great, any idea how to make it smooth scrolling, I assume with animate() or something right?

Comment: Change the second line with
$('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: y + 150
})

Comment: Thanks very much guys, you're the best.